# Getting a select's value with javascript

Tags: javascript, select

I have the following condensed form

```
<form name="thecars">
<select name="cars">
    <option value="mustang">Mustang</option>
    <option value="pinto">Pinto</option>
    <option value="pinto">Chevelle</option>
    <option value="pinto">Other</option>
</select>
</form>
```

I am trying to get the value of the selected car by the following but it is not working

```
selectedCar = document.forms["thecars"].elements["cars"].options[thecars.cars.options.selectedIndex].value;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct code would be:

```
var oForm = document.forms["thecars"];
var oDDL = oForm.elements["cars"];
var selectedCar = oDDL.value;
```

You can't get reference to the form by just using its name.

Answer (score 2):

Assign an ID to your `select` element:

```
<select name="cars" id="cars">
```

And you can get the value like this:

```
document.getElementById('cars').value
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an `=`. Change this

```
<form name "thecars">
```

To this

```
<form name="thecars">
```

Comment: Oh sorry that was a typo.The = is there.